# Google Sheets: Keeping static data aligned with data returned from a query as new data is added on top

Tags: google-sheets

first time poster but I've been able to solve a lot of problems with through the brilliant answers this community provides to users. So, firstly, thanks!

I'm making a Job Request tracking spreadsheet as well as using a Google Form to get the input data.

Jobs fall under categories of Building, IT, Keys, Maintenance and OHS as asked in the first question of the Google Form.

Depending on which category is selected, the user will go to a different section of a form with different questions.

That's all working great.

The data for all responses is saved in the same form response sheet and then using the Query function I have 5 sheets set up, one for each category, and I'm reading the relevant data into each sheet. The data is sorted based on date and time so that the most recent entry is at the top of the sheet.

To the right of each data set on each individual sheet I want to track whether the job is Completed, Pending, Not Approved. I want to track who gave it approval, and so on.

The problem is that when new data comes into the sheet it moves to the top as it is the most recent data. But the Completed, Pending, Not Approved, and other notes will not move down the sheet with the older data.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Form data added to the top of the Responses sheet, or is your query sorting/ordering the data based on some item which places the newer data at the top?  A link to a sample file would be helpful.

Comment: My static content (cells with a grey background in each of the IT, Keys, Maintenance and OHS sheets) will not move with my dynamic content (cells with a white background which are using the Query function).

The issue arises as any new response in the form will push old responses down a row but will not push data appended to the old response down with it.

Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe8TKXDE2kGJmSdkeWaO1jefxTsjYy_RRwR_6Ta-VZtQMq8Yg/viewform 

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A92hVHldgM4Z97mPh0S0wZfKgVbNCFho7KU_6bH038c/edit#gid=1156025096

Comment: Need a link to the spreadsheet receiving the data.  No the form.

Comment: sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A92hVHldgM4Z97mPh0S0wZfKgVbNCFho7KU_6bH038c/edit#gid=1156025096

Thanks @Karl_S

Comment: A reminder though -- this issue becomes apparent when new data is added through the form. It pushes the Query data (white background) further down the page, but the Manually entered data (grey background) does not move relative to the change. 
I need the Manually entered data to move with the Query data.

Comment: Your problem is that there is no way to move the manual data with the query outside of custom script.  If you are going to do that, you might as well create an HTML service which displays the data in a web app and allows for entering the manual portion. Another option would be to let the data come in as it is created (remove the order from the query) and Filter the data to show a smaller subset.